# Cannot download Office files in SharePoint browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office

I have a user whose permission level to a certain subsite is customized.

I'm currently investigating about user permissions and I found out that the minimum permission in order to download a file in SharePoint browser is the `View items` permission.

However, downloading Office files (like `docx, xlsx, pptx`) gives me an `Unauthorized Access` error, so I investigated again and I found out that it needs the `Open Items` permission together with the `View Items` permission in order to download any kind of files (including Office files).

My question is: What is in the `Open Items` permission that make the  `Unauthorized Access` error not occur in downloading Office files?

Or what is the Office files that makes an error when permission is only `View Items`?

Answer (score 1):

> View Items Permission

gives only view permission to the Items present in library like below.
therefore you can see the name of file only.

[image]

Actual file is associated with the name and for that

> Open Item permission

is required.

Comment: But in "View Items" permission, you can download pdf and other types of files except office files. Why?

Comment: It is well explained in this [link](http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2014/01/sp2010-excel-services-you-do-not-have-permissions-faulty-error/)